# Computing derivative of $\int_0^x \dfrac{1}{t^3 + 1} dt$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

I have been asked to find the derivative of this function:

$f(x) = \int_0^x \dfrac{1}{t^3 + 1} d\mathrm{t}$

So far the book I'm working on has covered till the first and second fundamental theorem of calculus.

I tried evaluating the indefinite integrals using Riemann's n-sum but wasn't able to reduce it further. Another attempt by me was using the second fundamental theorem:

$\int_0^x f'(t) \mathrm{d}t = f(x) - f(0)$

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: It is the *First Fundamental Theorem* which gives the answer.

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{x^3+1}$

Comment: Newton-Leibniz Formula

Comment: You can look up Leibnitz rule of differentiation under the integral sign which will help you to differentiate integrals.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus states that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x}f(t) \, dt = f(x)
$$
for all $x\in[a,b]$. Let $\displaystyle{f(t)=\frac{1}{t^3+1}}$ and set $a=0$. Since $f$ is a rational function, it is continuous on its domain, and so it is continuous on the nonnegative reals. This means that for any $b>0$,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{t^3+1} \, dt = \frac{1}{x^3+1}
$$
for all $x\in[0,b]$. Since $b$ can be made arbitrarily large,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{t^3+1} \, dt=\frac{1}{x^3+1}
$$
for all $x\in[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Deafferenting the second fundamental theorem you've given gives

$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x f^\prime (t)dt = f^\prime (x)$

as $f(0)$ does not change with x.

Letting

$f^\prime(t) = \frac{1}{t^3 + 1}$

then gives

$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x \frac{1}{t^3 + 1}dt = \frac{1}{x^3 + 1}$